# Como cargar en un iframe la redireccion del un formulario sin que se salga del sitio padre

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

html

```
 <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="500px"  frameborder="0">
```

javascript

```
  var xml = ""
  const form = document.createElement('form');     
  var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
  form.method = 'post';
  form.target = "iframe";
  form.action = "miurl";
  const hiddenField = document.createElement('textarea');
  hiddenField.style.visibility = "hidden";
  hiddenField.name = "RxInput";
  hiddenField.id = "RxInput";
  hiddenField.value = xml;
  form.appendChild(hiddenField);      
  iframe.appendChild(form);          
  form.submit();
```

En mi web escrita en vuejs tengo ese iframe, aqui lo que pasa es que cuando el form hace el submit del formulario eso redirecciona todo mi sitio hacia otra web, eso esta bien el resultado del hacer submit me debe redireccionar pero, quisiera que esa redireccion no me cerrara mi sitio, sino que cargara esa redireccion dentro del iframe, de manera que me queque mi sitio y el iframe dentro cargado con la otra web a la que me redirecciono el submit del formulario.

Comment: Detienes el submit, copias todo el form y lo envias al iframe y luego haces que el iframe haga el submit

Comment: cuando dices copiar todo el form dentro del iframe, es iframe.appendChild(form), y cuando se le hace submit al iframe hace el submit del form??

Comment: Gracias me funciono su comentario